# onSubmit does not allow a function call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, event-handling, onsubmit

So here is my code for that part which is correct, by the way:

```
function Form() {
   const [text, setText] = useState("");
   function handleSubmission(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }

   return (
      <form className="the-form" onSubmit={handleSubmission}>
       ....
```

My question is, why can I write onSubmit={handleSubmission()} instead? I thought that function is  called whenever a submission is made?

**Edit:** So this question is about asking why we have to pass the name of the function in the onSubmit attribute, rather than making a function call in it.

Comment: *"why can I write onSubmit={handleSubmission()} instead?"* - Well, what happens when you do that?  I suspect you'll observe that the function is called immediately rather than when the form is submitted.  There's nothing syntactically "wrong" about either way, they just do two different things.

Comment: Main differences between `onSubmit={handleSubmission()}` and `onSubmit={handleSubmission}`

When the syntax is `onSubmit={handleSubmission()}` it will execute handleSubmission immediately once the component render

When the syntax is `onSubmit={handleSubmission}` it will save the reference to that function and it will executed when you click submit

Comment: what onSubmit do is that it calls the function written in parenthesis but if u do it write like this `onSubmit={handleSubmission()}` this will not work because onSubmit job is to call a function, so u don't have to add these brackets and call the function again although it will throw an error but still don't do that.

Comment: Thank you guys very much! So it accepts a function as the argument, rather than executing the function there